# Best practice to load settings to the web application

Tags: javascript, json, web-applications, settings, electron

I have to load settings to an app when it's opened (*It's an [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) application and I'm loading settings from the local json file*)

---

I'm loading settings right after the page is loaded:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (document.readyState === 'complete'){
        loadSettings();
    }
}
```

but I think this is not the right way to do it because at first, the page sets inputs, like checkboxes, as they are in HTML file and only after that, changes their values again according to settings.
**I want to know what is the best practice to load the settings to a web app.**